# Do i need an a recycleview or an adapter for card view? having issue with going from cardview to activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-studio-2.2

I'm currently using just a card view for various items and details about those items. I'm ONLY using card view nothing else. should i add a recycleview and adapter or am i just okay with the card view? and if so how can i onlclick from card view to new activity?

```
enter code here public class RVA  extends Activity {
protected CardView mSidewalk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rva);
    //initialize//
    mSidewalk = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.rva_CV);

    //listen to cardview click
    mSidewalkCafe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RVA. this, RVA_Detail.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: my java code? or my xml?

Comment: @Keis sorry but your question doesn't make much sense. Neither a RecyclerView, nor an adapter, nor a CardView are a direct replacement of each other. They all have comeplete different purposes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the issue in your code,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_rva);
//initialize//
mSidewalk = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.rva_CV);

//listen to cardview click ------------(done change here)

mSidewalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RVA. this, RVA_Detail.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: no need of RecycleView or adapter for that. you done only a small mistake update your code. It will works for you.